# ajax function calling multiple times inside jquery validator

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate attachment field, below code is working but when i use `async` false

```
attachment:{
                required:{
                    depends: function () {
                        var res=false;
                        $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: baseUrl+"status",
                                    async: false,
                                    cache: false,
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function (result) {  res=result; }
                                });
                                return res;
                    }
                }
```

this function is called two times but when i remove `async:false` then validation is not working because `res` value is returned before the ajax call is executed.

Any solution. Thanks

Comment: Do you need to return res as you have already assigned res=result ?

Comment: It's entirely unclear why you have `ajax` inside of a `depends` inside of `required`; nor was it explained why getting called multiple times is a problem.  Where is the relevant HTML and the description about what you are trying to validate with this arrangement?  Is there a reason why this cannot be done with the `remote` method instead?

Comment: It appears as if you might misunderstand what `depends` is used for.  Your field is `required` depending on some condition.  Example:  a text field is only `required` when a checkbox is checked.  What purpose is being served by the ajax here?

Comment: @Sparky I want required `true` or `false` based on value return from server that's why i called ajax can you please provide some link for the same

Comment: Please review the official documentation for the plugin, which clearly defines how to use the `remote` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a bool variable and set is true when one time ajax called

```
$isAjaxSended = false;
attachment:{
            required:{
                depends: function () {
                    var res=false;
                    if(!isAjaxSended){
                              $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: baseUrl+"status",
                                async: false,
                                cache: false,
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (result) {isAjaxSended=true;  res=result; }
                              });
                            }
                            return res;
                }
            }
```